# google play store no connection retry

Tags: google-play-store

I recently got a new android device and my gmail account is logged in I have cleared cache and data on google play store but when trying to access the play store it says no connection. I am able to access the internet. when trying to download things from the google play website it does not list my phone as a device just my last two devices. please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Although the exact cause can not be said, and since you already tried `Clear cache` but below are few things that you may want to try:

1.Check the `date and time` of your device. This was the problem with majority of users complaining about this error message in their Google Play Store app.
If your date and time are not correctly set, you will again the “No connection – Retry” error message.
2.`Uninstall Updates`: Sometimes Google Play Store updates automatically, and If the above mentioned steps don’t help you, use the “uninstall updates” option of Play Store app, it will revert to previous version and may also fix the problem. 
3.Make Sure to Enter the Correct Google / Gmail Password

Another solution is to check your `Google / Gmail account password.` Did you change it and forget to re-enter in on your Android device? 
 As soon as you correctly enter your new password, your Android phone or tablet would be able to get all the Google services back on the device.